# Java 8 Stream extract datas from Map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Map<String,ExtractedData> extractedDatas` and I want to extract some data as return result.  I'm quite new with the Stream API and I don't understand what I have to do.  I tried with

```
public Map<String,ExtractedData> getExtractedData(String name)
{
    return extractedDatas.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith(name))
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().getFieldValue() != null && entry.getValue().getFieldValue() != "")
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(...);
}
```

What do I have to put in the `Collectors.toMap` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply have to pass the functions that map an element of your `Stream` to  both the key and the value of the output `Map`.

In your case it's simply the key and the value of the `Map.Entry` elements of the Stream.

```
public Map<String,ExtractedData> getExtractedData(String name)
{
    return extractedDatas.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith(name))
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().getFieldValue() != null && entry.getValue().getFieldValue() != "")
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying with `.collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(),entry -> entry.getValue()));` but in eclipse, when I type `entry.` I don't have the `getKey()` nor `getValue()` even if the the code is working.

Comment: What's the différence between `Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue`and `entry -> entry.getKey(),entry -> entry.getValue()` ?  Both are working.

Comment: @tweetysat Both are valid ways to express the implementation of a functional interface. The first is a method reference and the second is a lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it a bit different if you are OK altering the initial `Map`:

```
extractedDatas
     .entrySet()
     .removeIf(entry -> 
                 !(entry.getKey().startsWith(name) || 
                   entry.getValue().getFieldValue() != null && entry.getValue().getFieldValue() != "")
                  )
              );
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not the case.